# position fixed top gone wrong in mobile and stick to left

Tags: html, css, position, fixed

I have been designed a web site which top menu has fixed position
every thing is Okay, the site is not responsive. but in mobile the top menu stick to left,but it must be at center.
please help me, what can I do??
the website : http://www.infinitypub.com/

Answer (score 0):

Remove both `width` and `max-width` from the `body` element. I suspect you're trying to center the page, but you're doing it in an incorrect way.

Comment: in that way, I want to make it unresponsive, if i remove both width and max-width, everything blow up.

Comment: In that case I suppose I don't understand what you're trying to do.